# C# Apply Attribute to Dynamic object

Tags: c#

Assuming that I have the following Attribute class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MetadataAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool OutputDirection { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way that I can apply that attribute to a dynamic object.

```
new { [MetadataAttribute()]Foo = 3}
```

Comment: It's worth differentiating between dynamic typing (using the `dynamic` contextual keyword) and anonymous types, which aren't actually dynamic.

Comment: Attributes are applied to Definition not instance